# Можно ли surfaceTexture View сделать на весь экран?

Tags: java, android, камера, android-camera

Кто работал с api первой или второй камеры,  скажите есть ли возможность сделать SurfaceView на весь экран?

На моем примере,  я работаю с камера2api и картинка с камеры у меня устанавливается в кастомный autoFitTextureView,  который автоматически подбирает наилучший размер по экрану в зависимости от устройства.

Но почему то стандартная камера (я думаю что на всех устройствах)  выводит картинку на весь экран,  а все кастомные реализации камер которые я видел вне зависимости от того первое это апи или второе не дают такую возможность.

Картинка выводится обрезая часть экрана.  Я проверил несколько больших приложений на подобие того же Инстаграм и у них тоже когда делаешь фото,  то превью открывается не на весь экран...

Я так понимаю что нет возможности сделать кастомную камеру используя апи чтоб вывод картинки на весь экран как в стандартной камере?